# File Server Indexing Service for Mac OS Search

Tags: fileserver, file-search, indexing-service

Has anyone a solution for getting the MAC spotlight search facility to work with a remote file server (turnkey pdc, Debian) connecting by SMB.

I am at a loss.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I have found a work around. The problem consisted of 2 elements.

1) The Samba share was experiencing problems with file permissions with random mac written files. A cron job was required to chown and chmod these files.

2) MacOS is unable to search network drives! So I employed a app called "Easyfind" https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11076/easyfind on all Macs in the building. This enables the Mac users to search the network drives.